# Moving the cursor to the next character without the right arrow key

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

The reason for this is when writing code in an IDE it will automatically insert a close parenthesis when you type an open parenthesis. But then in order to skip pass the close parenthesis to continue on writing your code you have to press the right arrow key, which is really far away.

So, is there another key on the keyboard that can do the same job?

Comment: Which key would you prefer to use? You can certainly remap a key that is unused and perhaps closer to your hands ...

Comment: But what do you mean unused? All keys are used? Why would there be an unused key?

Comment: Not everybody uses their keyboard the same way. I have on mine a [かな] button to switch between the different Japanese input methods, but prefer to use [Cmd]+[Space] when jumping between languages. So my [かな] button has been remapped to instead do something else. If there is a key on your keyboard that you rarely or never use, then perhaps you could remap it. Just an option 

Comment: I would like to mape `Alt+L` to the right arrow key. How do I do that?

Comment: You can do that with AutoKey: `sudo apt install autokey-gtk`. Set that up and you’ll have a handy tool for quick keyboard actions 

Comment: I have installed it. But now how do I write the `py` that would execute the right arrow click when I press `Alt+l`